# Dry gurgling from shower drain

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

I just randomly heard a loud "dry" gurgling coming from my upstairs shower drain. It was draining slowly (assuming due to all the hair from a house full of females) so we have been using the basement shower. This particular shower hasn't been used in months. I haven't used the toilet or sink in this bathroom in about 2 hours and then I hear this weird sound. Is it possible to hear it from the clogged pipe hours after I used any other bathroom appliance?

Comment: Yes. Did you have a more specific question?

Comment: Just everything I've been reading about the noise and clogged drains says if you hear it "shortly after" or "immediately after" and it was atleast 2 hours since any toilet or sink were used in the bathroom.. and that the toilet and sink drain fine.. so it could still be just from the clogged drain?

Comment: Sometimes clogs dissolve slowly or simply slip through on their own schedule.

Comment: Now our toilet bowl water levels are low 

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how this site operates. If you have new information it should go in your question post, not in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If the shower has not been used for a long time, the water in the P-trap under the drain  will evaporate, so you no longer have a seal against the sewer lines. So anything else that drains into the sewer will make sound that can now come back through that shower drain. That by the way would also be letting sewer *gasses* back into your house, which is not good. Pour some water into that shower and see if the sound goes away.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a sewage issue in the drains..if it continues you may find sewage backing up into a lower drain area. Under a heavy load the water can litterally suck the toilet bowl dry. Rent a snake and send down the drain to clear clog or try some drain cleaner. A house full of women 1 might have flushed something that should not have been flushed